# How do I send the output of my Curl command to email with ssmtp?

Tags: linux, curl, echo, ngrok, ssmtp

Ok so I'm fairly new to Linux and I'm still learning as I go. Apologies I use the wrong terms and etc.

So I want my ngrok port curl output to be converted to text and send it as an email with ssmtp.

I did this:
`echo "$(curl localhost:4040/api/tunnels)" | ssmtp <email address>`

I've received the mail but the mail is empty. What could've been the problem here? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add text to you message body:"

```
ssmtp "<the message content>" <email address>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. So you mean like:

`ssmtp "$(curl localhost:4040/api/tunnels)" <email address>`

or

`ssmtp "echo "$(curl localhost:4040/api/tunnels)"" <email address>` ??

Comment: Nevermind, I tried a couple of things and adding `2>&1` at the end of curl did the trick! :)